# Multiple APK For Android App

Tags: android, android-manifest, apk, google-play

How can I publish two different APK for tablet and for phones separately. I already read google documents regarding this I have same package name and same key but I'm getting confused on what to put on version code right now my manifest are like this

For Phone

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jc.jcpremiere"
    android:versionCode="051250"
    android:versionName="1.2"
    android:largeHeap="true" >

       <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<supports-screens    
     android:smallScreens="true"
     android:normalScreens="true"
     android:largeScreens="false"
     android:xlargeScreens="false"/>
```

Tablet

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jc.jcpremiere"
    android:versionCode="053450"
    android:versionName="1.2"
    android:largeHeap="true"
     >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<supports-screens    
     android:smallScreens="false"
     android:normalScreens="false"
     android:largeScreens="true"
     android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
```

I always get that the other version is higher thus that version will be published. What version code should I input I can't go higher because it will publish the higher one. If I put the same version code it will just replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each build variant of your app must have a different version code. The part you are probably missing is the "Advanced mode" in the Google Play Developer Console. Once you click "Switch to advanced mode", you'll be able to have simultaneous APKs published.

Source: [Official Google Docs](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html)

And, here's some more helpful information on working with Android Studio and Gradle so that the system does more work for you: [Build Variants](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants)